# Is there a way to have subl only open a project if it's not already open?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, sublime-text-3

I'm using Windows 10 with multiple desktops and I'm trying to set up an environment where I can easily manage about a dozen different sublime workspaces. My goal is to run a command that will either open a certain sublime project, OR activate the window where that project is currently open, if it is. The issue I'm having is that sublime will always just open a new window with the project, whether or not it's already open.

Is there a way to get it to check currently open projects?

Comment: How do you open projects? From the GUI, the command-line or within Sublime Text?

Comment: Any/or, but I need a non-gui option.